# Need multi select checkbox drop-down, when option selected textbox should be displayed beside option in same drop-down

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, multi-select

Something like this:-

[image: UI image]

Need multi-select checkbox drop-down, when option selected textbox should be displayed beside option in the same drop-down

I coded it, but the textbox appears down.

My code:

```js
$(".hidden-textbox").hide();
$("select#specialHandling").change(function() {
  var selected = [];
  for (var option of document.getElementById('specialHandling').options) {
    if (option.selected) {
      selected.push(option.value);
      console.log("Selected Value:-" + option.value);
    }
  }
  if (selected.indexOf("FLEXWARE") > -1 || selected.indexOf("Service Migration Order") > -1) {
    $(".hidden-textbox").show();
  } else {
    $(".hidden-textbox").hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.select-checkbox {
  background: url(images/select-arrow-down.png) no-repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-position: right 15px center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 9px 40px 9px 9px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  overflow-y: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  appearance: none;
  text-overflow: '';
  word-wrap: normal;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.select-checkbox option::before {
  content: "\2610";
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
}

.select-checkbox option:checked::before {
  content: "\2611";
}

.hidden-textbox {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="heading-group2">Special Handling</h2>
<div class="row">
  <div class="select-checkbox">
    <input id="specialHandling" name="specialHandling" multiple>
    <option value="IPFLEX TN MOVE">IPFLEX TN MOVE</option>
    <option value="FLEXWARE">FLEXWARE </option>
    <option value="SD-WAN">SD-WAN</option>
    <option value="US Onshore Delivery">US Onshore De`enter code here`livery</option>
    <option value="US Citizen Delivery">US Citizen Delivery</option>
    <option value="Custom Order with DLP">Custom Order with DLP</option>
    <option value="Service Migration Order">Service Migration Order</option>

    </select>
    <input type="text" class="hidden-textbox" name="Reference Designator" id="referenceDesignator" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Please advise me how can I resolve this.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap try to use plugin bootstrap-select

Comment: Is it possible without Bootstrap

Comment: <input  id="specialHandling" name="specialHandling" multiple > is wrong I corrected it with  <select id="specialHandling" name="specialHandling" multiple >